Reduce the Mat Form Field Height in Angaular Material 17
We recently upgraded our angular Project from 13 to 17 and also we upgraded Angular Material to 17. But after migration Materiel 17 (MDC), we are unable to reduce the form field height.
Any help is is much appreciated.
Angular Material 13

Angular Material 17


Billure please share the minimal reproducible code to check the issue! if possible a stackblitz where the issue happens

I have added the images for your reference. Please note that there is no changes in the code.

Apart from the answer below, there might be some custom CSS that is not working now causing the input elements to look large, recheck the CSS and adjust it for material 17

To get rid of the padding at the bottom, you can use subscript sizing "dynamic". You can set this for the whole app via the MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS injection token.
Also you can adjust the density of the form fields, which will decrease their height. To do this for the whole app, add the following SCSS code:
@use "@angular/material" as mat;

:root {
  @include mat.form-field-density(-4);
}

For more information see the theming docs.

Unfortunately it didn't make much changes

For me this works. Did you put this code into your styles.scss?

I tried it in theme.scss.. since our application works on CSS based we don't have the styles.scss

Without a minimal reproduction, I'm afraid I can't assist you further.

The only predefined height in the material form field is the line-height.
You can change this height with a css variable called --mat-form-field-container-text-line-height.
mat-form-field.custom-line-height {
  --mat-form-field-container-text-line-height: 40px;
}

Check a StackBlitz with a working example here.

Note: A lot of the "new" Material MDC components can/should be configured with css variables. Those can be easily found when you inspect the material element in your developer tools in your browser.
For examplethis form field has following properties in css:
.mat-mdc-form-field {
    --mat-mdc-form-field-floating-label-scale: 0.75;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    text-align: left;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: var(--mat-form-field-container-text-font);
    line-height: var(--mat-form-field-container-text-line-height);
    font-size: var(--mat-form-field-container-text-size);
    letter-spacing: var(--mat-form-field-container-text-tracking);
    font-weight: var(--mat-form-field-container-text-weight);
}

You see that many of those are defined with variables and can be easily overwritten with your own custom values the same way as I demonstrated with the line-height in the example above.
